How can I optimize this working TAT query
I need query for TAT report .. I need total working hours only on office hours i.e, 09:00 to 06:00 if time is more that 6:00 the adjust the time to next day starts from 09:00 and also include public holidays. If there is any public holiday then time should add to next day of holiday
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME, @EndDate DATETIME;

SELECT @StartDate = MIN(StartTime), @EndDate = MAX(EndTime) 
FROM Tasks1;

WITH Calendar AS 
(
    SELECT CONVERT(date, @StartDate) AS Date

    UNION ALL

    SELECT DATEADD(day, 1, Date) FROM Calendar
    WHERE Date < CONVERT(date, @EndDate)
)
SELECT DISTINCT
    TaskID,
    (CASE 
         WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, StartTime) >= 9 AND DATEPART(HOUR, 
         EndTime) <= 18 AND DATEPART(WEEKDAY, EndTime) BETWEEN 2 
         AND 6 THEN DATEDIFF(HOUR, StartTime, EndTime)

         WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, StartTime) >= 9 
         AND DATEPART(WEEKDAY, StartTime) BETWEEN 2 AND 6 
         THEN DATEDIFF(HOUR, StartTime, CAST(CONVERT(datetime, 
         CONVERT(date, StartTime)) + ' 18:00:00' AS datetime))
         WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, EndTime) <= 18 AND 
         DATEPART(WEEKDAY,EndTime) BETWEEN 2 AND 6  
         THEN DATEDIFF(HOUR, CAST(CONVERT(date, EndTime) AS 
         datetime) + ' 09:00:00', EndTime)

         ELSE
        CASE WHEN CONVERT(date, StartTime) = CONVERT(date,EndTime) 
        THEN DATEDIFF(HOUR, CAST(CONVERT(date, EndTime) AS 
        datetime) + ' 09:00:00', EndTime)

        ELSE DATEDIFF(HOUR, CAST(CONVERT(date, Calendar.Date) AS 
        datetime) + ' 09:00:00', EndTime) END END) AS 
        Working_Hours
FROM 
    Tasks1
JOIN 
    Calendar ON Calendar.Date BETWEEN CAST(CONVERT(date, StartTime) AS datetime) 
             AND CAST(CONVERT(date, EndTime) AS datetime)
LEFT JOIN 
    PublicHolidays ON Calendar.Date = CONVERT(date, PublicHolidays.HolidayDate)
WHERE 
    PublicHolidays.HolidayDate IS NULL 
    OR DATEPART(WEEKDAY, PublicHolidays.HolidayDate) BETWEEN 2 AND 6;


Please add table definitions for all tables(so we can see indexes) as text and an execution plan. Tidier code would also help. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

You can materialize your calendar cte as an indexed table together with the DATEPART(WEEKDAY,holidate) stuff, otherwise don't see much improvements here. Btw, DATEPART(WEEKDAY,...) is non-deterministic so it should be used with care (it depends on session settings with can vary for users)

??'I need total working hours ' - but there is no aggregation in the query - quite the opposite in fact given the select distinct.

help me to get a solution on this

You claim in the title that  the published query works, given that it does not produce the result I expect I have some doubts that you published the working code. It would also help if you published sample data and expected outcome as text.

need no of hours woked by a user based on (need to create a TAT (turnaround time) report for leads data in sql server which considers the bussiness hours as the duration and excludes the holidays)  based on this description
